# ReferenceError: Sginals is not defined in Vue app

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

This error occured and has been logged to my console (including call stack):

```text
ReferenceError: Sginals is not defined
  at eval (index.vue:113:1)  
    at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/signalsCall/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:1454:1)  
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849:30)  
    at fn (app.js:151:20)  
    at eval (index.vue:1:1)  
    at ./src/views/signalsCall/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:6271:1)  
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849:30)  
    at fn (app.js:151:20)  
    at eval (index.vue:1:1)  
    at ./src/views/signalsCall/index.vue (app.js:6259:1)
```

Here is my code:

```
export default {
  name: Sginals,
  //   components: { CrudButs },
  data() {
    return {
    //   dialogFormPermissions: false,
    //   dialogFormVisible: false,
    //   handelCloseOnClickOut: false,
    //   titleDialog: 'ایجاد',
      labelPosition: 'top',
      listLoading: false,
      formLabelWidth: '120px',
      tableData: [],
      currentRow: [],
      urlexport: ''
    }
  },
```

How could I fix this error?

Comment: Well, is `Sginals` [sic] defined?

Comment: yes i have already done but  i forgot to use single coat . tnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you that `Sginals` isn't defined anywhere. If this is supposed to be a variable, you'll need to assign it before using it

```
const Sginals = 'something'
```

If that's just supposed to be the name as a string, you're missing quotes:

```
name: 'Sginals'
```

Should it also be `Signals`?

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked. I forgot to use single coat for obj